# Why Unity WebGL build inputs doesnt work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, webgl

On Editor everything is fine, but When I'm trying on build Getkey() Getkeydown() GetkeyUp() Doesnt work. I Tested with Debug When I push the buttons nothing happen on build. How can I solve that ?